# Anyone know of a good CURL wrapper for PHP that can be extended upon?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Specifically I am looking for a good OOP PHP CURL class that can be extended to maybe have multi threads and proxy support. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Frameworks Zend_Http_Client has a curl adapter: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html